# Hadamard matrix in Ruby is not unitary although it should be?

Tags: ruby, matrix

Even when trying to define Hadamard matrix in Ruby by using rational numbers (which helps us sometimes to keep good precision) the result is that Hadamard matrix is not unitary.

```
m = (1 / Math.sqrt(2)).to_r * Matrix[[1,  1],
                                     [1, -1]]
```

Then using available class Matrix method:

```
m.unitary?
```

results in **false** and result of **m*m** multiplication is as below:

```
Matrix[[2535301200456458353478625262249/2535301200456458802993406410752, 0/1], 
       [0/1, 2535301200456458353478625262249/2535301200456458802993406410752]]
```

But in reality Hadamard is unitary matrix.

How to fix that and other cases in best way globally?

Comment: `Math.sqrt(2) * Math.sqrt(2)` isn't `2` although it should be. Ruby only has integers, floats and rational numbers. None of these can represent √2 or 1/√2 exactly. As a result, your matrix is just an approximation.

Comment: (there's also `Complex` but it won't help either; and `BigDecimal` might have arbitrary precision, but not unlimited)